# Label data according to percentile

Tags: mysql

I have a table name `temp` with column `customer_id` , `sum` and I need to add extra column `customer_label` (may be on view) which is 1 if customer lies in top 10% according to value of `sum`, 2 if lies within 10%-20%, 3 if lies within 20%-60%, 4 if lies within 60-100%. How can I do this?

Some sample data is included at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e8e0/5/1)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e8e0/5/1

Comment: So, for 50 customers, the Top 5 should have `label=1`, the next 5 `label=2`, the next 20 `lable=3`, etc.?

Comment: @ypercube yap... but this 50 customer is just for test case... Data row may vary...

Comment: @ypercube could you help me to write the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select customer_id,sum,case 
when pct_row<=0.10 then 1
when pct_row>0.10 and pct_row<=0.20 then 2
when pct_row>0.20 and pct_row<=0.60 then 3
when pct_row>0.60 then 4
end as customer_label from (
select customer_id,sum,(@curRow := @curRow+1)/c as pct_row
from temp t 
jOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
JOIN (SELECT @curRow2 := 0) r2 
join (select count(*) c from temp) s
order by sum desc) p;
```

sqlfiddle :- [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bedbf/27/0)

I don't know whether this is efficient method or not but work fine for small data set.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE (CUSTOMER_ID,SUM,ROW_NUMBERS,CUSTOMER_LABER )
AS
(
SELECT TOP(10) PERCENT WITH TIES A.customer_id,A.SUM ,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID) ROW_NUMBERS ,
CASE WHEN CUSTOMER_ID BETWEEN 0 AND 4 THEN '1' ELSE NULL END CUSTOMER_LABER
FROM PERCENTS A
ORDER BY A.CUSTOMER_ID
),
CTE2 (CUSTOMER_ID,SUM,ROW_NUMBERS,CUSTOMER_LABER )
AS
(
```

SELECT TOP(20) PERCENT WITH TIES A.customer_id,A.SUM ,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID) ROW_NUMBERS ,
CASE WHEN CUSTOMER_ID BETWEEN 6 AND 10 THEN '2' ELSE NULL END CUSTOMER_LABER
FROM PERCENTS A
ORDER BY A.CUSTOMER_ID
),
CTE3 (CUSTOMER_ID,SUM,ROW_NUMBERS,CUSTOMER_LABER )
AS
(
SELECT TOP(60) PERCENT WITH TIES A.customer_id,A.SUM ,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID) ROW_NUMBERS ,
CASE WHEN CUSTOMER_ID BETWEEN 11 AND 30 THEN '3' ELSE NULL END CUSTOMER_LABER
FROM PERCENTS A
ORDER BY A.CUSTOMER_ID
),

CTE4 (CUSTOMER_ID,SUM,ROW_NUMBERS,CUSTOMER_LABER )
AS(
SELECT TOP(100) PERCENT WITH TIES A.customer_id,A.SUM ,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID) ROW_NUMBERS ,
CASE WHEN CUSTOMER_ID BETWEEN 30  AND 50 THEN '4' ELSE NULL END CUSTOMER_LABER
FROM PERCENTS A
ORDER BY A.CUSTOMER_ID
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE CUSTOMER_LABER IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM CTE2 WHERE CUSTOMER_LABER IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM CTE3 WHERE CUSTOMER_LABER IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM CTE4 WHERE CUSTOMER_LABER IS NOT NULL

Comment: MySQL does not have `TOP`. No CTEs either. No `ROW_NUMBER()` function either.

Comment: Ohh sorry  I have not seen that your question is from MySql

Comment: see the `Tag` ...